# Swift - handle UICollectionViewCell Tap

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am having a weird behavior when tapping on my `UICollectionViewCell`.

This is my `cell`-Setup:

```
    class ContentCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let buttonView: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        v.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.5, height: 1.5)
        v.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        v.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        return v
    }()

    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.textAlignment = .center
        return v
    }()

    let testLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.text = "Test Label"
        v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 18)
        v.textColor = .darkGray
        v.textAlignment = .center
        return v
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }


    func commonInit() -> Void {
//        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
        contentView.addSubview(testLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(buttonView)
        // constrain label to all 4 sides
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            buttonView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            buttonView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            buttonView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            buttonView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:150),

            testLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonView.bottomAnchor,constant: 1),
            testLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            testLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            testLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
        ])
        buttonView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(listTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func listTapped(_ sender: Any){
        print("listTapped")
    }
}
```

The weird thing is, if I tap on my cell for a short time `@objc func listTapped` gets called. But if click it for a longer timer the "click"-animation happens but my `func listTapped` does not get called. So it seems I have two different "click"-handlers??

I am quite new to this so I am grateful if one of you could explain to me what causes that problem.

Comment: it's a tap not a long press

Comment: what do you mean by that? If I long press it I get the "highlight"-animation

Comment: can you try my answer @Chris and tell me if its working or not

Comment: @Was'SiimBenHssen nope, not working. I can still either "tap" it or "press" it

Answer (score 0):

try to remove this code and change the tap action with tap gesture

```
// remove this code

buttonView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(listTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

// add tap gesture in the top of your commitinit function

let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(listTapped(_:)))
    tap.delegate = self
    buttonView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```